# Newlines in foreach array string - Powershell

Tags: powershell, text, foreach

Why do I get newlines in the following:

```
[string[]]$lines= "001 AALTON, Alan .....25 Every Street","002 BROWN, James .... 101 Browns Road","008 FLANAGAN, Lesley .... 1 Lovers Lane"

foreach ($line in $lines) {
    $line
}
```

Output:

```
001 AALTON, Alan .....25 Every Street
002 BROWN, James .... 101 Browns Road
008 FLANAGAN, Lesley .... 1 Lovers Lane
```

The foreach [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.2) make no mention of newlines. My loop does not contain newline instruction. And it's obviously not in the source data?

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The newlines are a *formatting artifact*, they're not part of your array elements: PowerShell's output formatting system renders each element of a collection of strings / primitive types on its own line, and the same applies to outputting instances of such types one by one to the success output stream, which is what your `foreach` statement does.

To give a simple example: `'foo', 'bar'`, `'foo'; 'bar'` and `foreach ($s in 'foo', 'bar') { $s }` all result in the same output:

```
foo
bar
```

If you need a different representation, create a string in the desired format yourself; e.g.:

```
PS> $lines -join ', '

001 AALTON, Alan .....25 Every Street, 002 BROWN, James .... 101 Browns Road, 008 FLANAGAN, Lesley .... 1 Lovers Lane
```

Comment: I realize that this thread is a little hypothetical. But if I add the following to my $line output. `$line | Out-File lines.txt -Append` I get newlines. And it seems interesting to me that this is by default. That is; I need to specify the parameter `-NoNewline` Which I would have thought would be the default (if I followed your logic of newlines being a formatting artifact)